# What order do split TXT records get assembled in?

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim, txt-record

As per [RFC4408 3.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1.3), a TXT record can be split up with quotation marks and will be reassembled properly - this is a way of getting around the 255 character limit on record size.

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 .... first" "second string..."
```

MUST be treated as equivalent to

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 .... firstsecond string..."
```

If a record has 3 or more parts, what determines the order in which the records are concatenated?

Comment: RFC 4408 is obsoleted by [RFC 7308](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-3.3). It's best not to use it as a reference. Not that it changes anything about your question...it's just referencing the format described by [RFC 1035](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts are always reassembled in order.  The 255 character limit is on parts of the TXT record.  Without EDNS0, there is an addtional 512 byte limit for a UDP response.  However, this does not apply to a TCP response.

Comment: Reassembled in order of what - time entered into a database? Position in dig query? Order that the server returns the records in?

Comment: @emc Order listed in the rdata for that record. This would be left to right as read in a zone file.

Comment: Aha, new terminology... http://superuser.com/questions/657789/format-of-txt-data-in-dns-record

Comment: @AndrewB how does the rdata get set - automatically by the DNS server?

Comment: @emc Yep! rdata contains the record type and associated payload. ([RFC 1034](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034#section-3.6))

Answer (score 2):

Also, you may encounter a problem with AWS Route53, where

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 .... first""second string..."
```

IS treated as an equivalent to

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 .... firstsecond string..."
```

But if you use spaces... the following WILL FAIL:

```
IN TXT "v=spf1 .... first" "second string..."
```

Comment: Whoa, interesting find, but not a 100% match for what I'm observing. A space (or no space at all) in the Route 53 console works fine for DKIM, so `"foo""bar"` and `"foo"<space>"bar"` are both treated as creating a single record with two values (and a space between the two is shown by `dig` but they concatenate correctly), while `"foo"<enter>"bar"` in the Route 53 console creates two TXT records (`"foo"` and `"bar"` shown on two different lines, in random order, by `dig`). https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-resolve-dkim-text-record-error/